# Is it possible to have an indefinite number of type parameters in Java?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, type-parameter

I'm making an event system in Java and I've run into a problem in writing the Listener part.

This is my current `Listener` class:

```
public interface Listener<E extends Event<?>> {
    public void handleEvent(E event);
}
```

I want to keep it expandable in a way that I can have one Listener class that can be flexible to any Event type, i.e. `Listener<Foo>` and `Listener<Bar>` instead of `FooListener` and `BarListener`, but I also want implementing classes to be able to listen to multiple events.

My problem is that a class cannot implement the Listener class with two different type parameters.

```
public class MultiListener implements Listener<Foo>, Listener<Bar> {
    // does not work
}
```

I know it's possible for a *method* to have an indefinite number of parameters, like this:

```
public void toInfinityAndBeyond(String... lotsOfStrings) {

}
```

But can my `Listener` class have an indefinite number of type parameters to listen to multiple events?

```
public class MultiListener implements Listener<ThisEvent, ThatEvent, AnotherEvent> {
    // hypothetical
}
```

Comment: Definitly not. Everything is limited in the real world ;) - the varargs are implemented through arrays so the maximum number of arguments is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Listener<Foo>` and `Listener<Bar>` are really the exact same interface, due to generic [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  So this isn't possible (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand generics, but I've found they tend to make Java, a statically typed language, a lot more static.  This can be a good thing.  But what you are trying to do is rather dynamic.

So in this case I would dump the generics.  Make Foo and Bar extend or implement Event.  (Event with no "<>".)  Make sure the Event class has enough methods that the code in Listener's handleEvent() doesn't need multiple `if`'s using `instanceof`; so it can just deal with plain Event objects.  (Mind, the occasional `instanceof` won't hurt anything, usually.)